# arguments limit php exec() to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, php

Testing how long will it take to pass 50000 arguments from php to a bash script, turns that **I cannot pass even 1000 arguments from php to a bash script at once, unless I can?**

```
PHP:
    
$array = fetch_results_from_working_pool_temp_table ();
$outputfile = "/var/www/html/outputFile";
$pidfile = "/var/www/html/pidFile";
$id = "";
$array_check=array();

foreach ( $array as $row => $column ) {
    $id .= $column ['id'];
        $id .= " "; 
        
}
$cmd = "sudo /bin/bash /var/www/html/statistics/pass_all.sh {$id}";
exec( sprintf ( "%s >> %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile ) );


bash:

#!/bin/bash
for ip in "$@"
do 
    echo "${ip}" 
done
```

So my **php** passes arguments to the **bash**, bash prints to the **outputFile** along with any errors. **pidfile** will hold pid of the process that was launched with this exec.
**The command is not even being executed because I see no process launched.** Is there any limit for passed arguments in exec? or from PHP or in Linux shell?
**I am running php 5.4 and Linux Redhat 7**
I want to run processes using GNU parallel but because PHP is single-threaded (there are libraries to pass this but I would prefer to avoid that).
Maybe I could pass it somehow to a text file and exec to a script that pulls from this text file? Help!

```
**Update: my machine limits:**
#getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
 
#ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256634
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most systems, the kernel limits the size of the arguments to the `execve()` syscall (command line args + environment vars). On Linux, the limit is related to the maximum stack size, though usually you'd get at least 2 MB total for the default stack size limit of 8 MB. It also limits a *single* argument to 128 kB, see e.g. [Is there a maximum to bash file name expansion (globbing) and if so, what is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356386/170373) and [Raise 128KiB limit on environment variables in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336934/170373)

If PHP runs `sh -c 'command line'` when you call `exec("command line")` then the argument to `-c` could well exceed that 128 kB limit. The fact that the command line gets subsequently split into distinct words by the shell wouldn't help.

Comment: That was very helpful, would you happen to know simplest way to go around it?

Comment: @dwt.bar, well, actually, no. I tried to look it up, and found this question on SE: [Run executable from php without spawning a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595044/run-executable-from-php-without-spawning-a-shell). It doesn't seem to indicate it would be too easy

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu. I believe that instead of handing over too many arguments to a new process, make use of a shell built-in (echo) or iterate over the arguments with a control structure (for loop).
*Without calling exec, there is no ARG_MAX limitation. So it would explain why shell builtins are not restricted by ARG_MAX.
So maybe I could save all the arguments to a file and read line by line in my shell script that I try to pass via exec() in PHP.
source: http://shaoguangleo.github.io/2017/03/23/linux-command-line-arg-max/

Comment: @dwt.bar, saving the data to a temporary file is probably smart

Answer (score 1):

When you have this many arguments, you want to pass them to GNU Parallel via standard input (stdin) or via files.

I would do something like (untested):

```
$f = popen("parallel","w");
fwrite($f,$commands);
close ($f);
```

This way you may be able to avoid the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

So with all your help here is my solution:
PHP:

```
function scan_targets() {

$targetsFile= "[absolute path to the file]/targets";

$array_with_targets = fetch_from_db (); //function that gets me all the targets
$outputfile = "[absolute path to the file]/outputFile"; //output from parallel script
$pidfile = "[absolute path to the file]/pidFile"; //PID of the process
$target = "";

foreach ( $array_with_targets as $row => $column ) {
    $id .= $column ['id'];
        $id .= " "; 
}
file_put_contents($targetsFile, $ip) ;
$cmd = "/bin/bash [absolute path to the file]/pass_targets.sh";
exec( sprintf ( "%s >> %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile ) );
```

BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash

#appending arguments to the command
targets_array=()
IFS=" "
while read -r field || [ -n "$field" ]; do
    targets_array+=("$field")
done <[absolute path to the file]/targets
    
parallel bash [absolute path to the file]/check.sh ::: $targets_array
```

You can also run your parallel with -Dall option to have more context what's happening, I managed to scan almost 40.000 hosts in 7h. Web server added all the targets to the file in seconds and as my exec launches a background process used does not have to wait for the result (we are outputting it to the file).

And the check.sh script is also updating Mariadb database record for a particular target as it goes.